# How to debug 'Your request cannot be processed' in JHipster?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, jhipster

I have a issue running JHipster. I have a working application that runs fine with the embedded 
tomcat server. But when I deploy the the war file after mvn -Pprod to an external tomcat server, 
the home url shows the following error. I don't have made any explicit changes for html5 etc.

```
Your request cannot be processed
Sorry, an error has occurred.

Status: Not Found (Not Found)
Message: No message available
```

My main doubt is, how do I debug this scenario? I cannot see any stack trace in the console or 
server log. I am accessing the url:
For my war : **Project1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war**

I am accessing the following url (in the external server) :

*http://localhost:8080/Project1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as specified in the [documentation](https://jhipster.github.io/production/) when you are deploying to a container, you should deploy the ***Project1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.original*** file to the container, i.e. remove the suffix ***.original*** from ***Project1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.original*** file and deploy it to your container. As debug option start watching the log of your container to see that the deployment was good and then you can have a look at the exploded war to check if all the files that you are expecting have been included into your war.

Comment: Dear @duderoot the suffix .original was already removed before deployment. The log indicates successful startup of application. All expected files are present in the exploded folder.

Comment: then you need to check in $TOMCAT_HOME$/webapps/Project1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ for the idex.html. Because of the 404 result, it means that the file is not there. On the other hand you say that all the expected files are there, i.e. something is not consisten :(

Comment: You were right, my war was incomplete. I only checked the class files and totally ignored the index.html. Now after reverting some changes I made to pom and doing 'mvn clean install' I'm getting the war file that works well. Thanks.

Comment: Dear @Albin can you give more details on steps you tried for solving the issue? what changes you applied in your pom file.

Answer (score 0):

After I generate my project, and without any local change, I started my application using `mvnw` (I'm using windows). When I tried to access http://localhost:8080 I got that error. So I just had to restart the application and everything worked. So I had to do it like this

1. `CTRL+C` to stop the app
2. and start again the server `mvnw`